# Efficiently Plotting NIntegrate with Variable Integration Limit

Tags: plotting, function-construction, integral-equations

Consider $g(x)$ which is mathematically defined as

$g(x) = \int^{x}_{x_0} f(x') dx'$ such that $x\in\{x_0,x_{max}\}$.

If $f(x)$ can only be integrated numerically, one could define the following *Mathematica* function

```
g[x_]:= NIntegrate[f[xPrime],{xPrime,x0,x}]
```

Plotting this would take an eternity since every time `x` increases by an increment, the integral must be re-evaluated from `x0` to the new `x` again and again. How can one efficiently plot $g(x)$ such that the plotting time is on the order of evaluating $g(x_{max})$? Equivalently, what is the most efficient way to generate an `InterpolatingFunction` for $g(x)$ over the range $x_0$ to $x_{max}$?

---

Note: Conversion to differential equation and using `NDSolve` is not a valid method as suggested [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84526/plotting-nintegrate).

Note: Related but not a duplicate of "[Plotting results of NIntegrate with variable integration limit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81222/plotting-results-of-nintegrate-with-variable-integration-limit)".

Comment: Plotting `g = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == f[xPrime], y[x0] == 0}, y, {xPrime, x0, xmax}]` seems a valid method to me.  Why do you say it's not?  Please show an `f` that it does not work on.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(23854)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23854), [(47580)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47580)